# Bootstrap - How can you visually see what bootstrap media query is currently being applied, in web applications using JQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bookmarklet

Often when I'm developing a web application, that needs to be responsive, I use the Bootstrap CSS framework, Bootstrap is excellent for developing responsive web application. After developing many pages, I found that I was constantly having to workout what a page would look like under each of the media queries, which soon becomes a pain.

You typically do this either by having a few different devices around (It's always worth testing your application on as many devices as possible, but not every minute) or using the browser debugger (the device mode testing feature wasn't around when i started responsive development).

Is there a way to have some kind of indication on my page, of the current active media query, that is separate to the website?

i.e. would show:
   `XS, SM, MD, LG`

Comment: _browser debugger (this feature is a relatively new addition to browsers)_ if 8+ years is new...I guess.

Comment: lol - yeah, good point, I've reworded it

Comment: Dev tools have been around roughly the same amount of time since the spec was developed for `@media` queries - Safari 4, released in 2008 had dev tools built in. That said, that's a nice script to visually see the break point if you don't want to memorize the breakpoint numbers

Comment: the device mode testing tool was added much later on, but this wasnt what i was asking anyhow.. ref `https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/device-mode-v2`

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a simple way to do this, and it can be used on any page that is using Bootstrap and also has JQuery, and without changing the actual pages on the server side.

You can do this by creating a `bookmarklet` (ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet).

A `bookmarklet` is simply a bookmark that has javascript code in the URL.

Create a new bookmark, and set its name to something easy to remember: 
like: `Bootstrap Info`

And then set its URL to one of the line of JQuery below - depending on bootstrap version, but you can have one bookmarklet for each.

For **bootstrap 3** use this, as the URL:

```
javascript: $("body").append("<div style='position: fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; width:42px; height:37px; background-color:AntiqueWhite; border:2px solid gray;'><span class='visible-xs text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>XS</span><span class='visible-sm text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>SM</span><span class='visible-md text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>MD</span><span class='visible-lg text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>LG</span></div>");
```

and for **bootstrap 4** use this:

```
javascript: $("body").append("<div style='position: fixed; bottom:0px; left:0px; width:42px; height:37px; background-color:AntiqueWhite; border:2px solid gray;'><span class='d-block d-sm-none text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>XS</span><span class='d-none d-sm-block d-md-none text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>SM</span><span class='d-none d-md-block d-lg-none text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>MD</span><span class='d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>LG</span><span class='d-none d-xl-block text-center' style='font-weight:900; font-size:18pt;'>XL</span></div>");
```

Then when you navigate to a page which uses bootstrap and has JQuery, run your `bookmarklet` by selecting it, as you would any bookmark.

A small indicator will now appear at the bottom left corner of your window showing you what the current media query is.

Now if you resize your browser window, the indicator will change dynamically, as you change between the different media queries. Making it easy to see how your page looks under each query.

This is done by having a small amount of html, which is floated on the screen, which uses the bootstrap : `visible-xs, visible-sm, visible-md, visible-lg` classes in bootstrap 3 (and `d-block d-sm-none` etc..., for bootstrap 4). So only the spans that match with current media query CSS have their relevant text is shown.

You could take this further, to display other information, by adding other bookmarklets. For instance, showing an indication of grid column boundaries, along the bottom of your screen.